# Assign JSON Values to Fields in Test

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, json

**Markup**

```
<apex:page controller="skillproficiencycontroller" id="p"> 
<apex:form id="f"> 
    <script> 
    var state = {};
    function passState() {
        document.getElementById("p:f:hiddenField").value = JSON.stringify(state);
        passStateToController();
    }
    function myFunction( value, id) { 
        state[id] = value;
        console.log(state);
    }
    </script> 

    <apex:inputHidden value="{!hidden}" id="hiddenField"/>
    <apex:pageBlock > 
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!skilllist}" var="s"> 
            <apex:column value="{!s.Name}"/> 
            <apex:column headerValue="Proficiency"> 
                <apex:selectRadio value="{!Selected}" onclick="myFunction(this.value,'{!s.id}');"> 
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" /> 
                </apex:selectRadio> 
            </apex:column> 
        </apex:pageblockTable> 
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton onclick="passState(); return false;" value="Save" />
            <apex:actionFunction name="passStateToController" action="{!Save}" reRender="hiddenField" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

**Method**

```
public void Save() {
    List<Skill_Details__c >skilldetailslist = new List<Skill_Details__c >();

    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(hidden);
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() != JSONToken.START_OBJECT && parser.getCurrentToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT){

            Skill_Details__c sd = new Skill_Details__c();
            sd.Skill__c = id.valueOf(parser.getText());
            parser.nextToken();
            sd.Proficiency__c = parser.getText();
            skilldetailslist.add(sd);
        }
    }
    //system.debug(skilldetailslist);
    Insert skilldetailslist;
}
```

This Piece of code in the test class is throwing an error while running:

> System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.

```
vfac.Selected='false';
vfac.hidden = '[ {\"a0H8A000001XO5QUAW\":\"First\"} ]';
string hidden = vfac.hidden;

if(hidden!= Null) {
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(hidden);
    Preference__c p = new Preference__c();
    p.Contact__c =  testcon.Id;
    p.Shift__c =Id.valueof(parser.getText());
    p.Preference__c = 'First';
    p.status__c = 'Aligned';
    prefrencelist.add(p);
}

nextPage  = vfac.save().getUrl();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please at least make an effort to ask a question?  Perhaps include something about what you've tried, what errors you're getting, and where you're stuck?

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] and also [Markdown help](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

If hidden is a public attribute of your controller, simply set hidden.

```
MyController mc = new MyController();

mc.hidden = "some json";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the exact sequence of things in your controller, test class, etc or the exact line that is throwing the error because those details are missing from your question BUT:

You have ONE token and Value defined in your code:

`vfac.hidden = '[ {\"a0H8A000001XO5QUAW\":\"First\"} ]';`

Then in your class you grab the first token:

`while (parser.nextToken() != null) {`

and the text

When you get to this line you get the next token but it does not exist so the getText fails because the parser is null (no next token).

```
parser.nextToken();
            sd.Proficiency__c = parser.getText();
```

If you are trying to validate functionality during a test class, this would be a good negative use case to ensure you handle this situation properly. However, you should also try to use a valid value with multiple tokens etc.